# Unable to build wireshark in the centOS 5.3

Tags: wireshark, centos-5, build, qt4

I downloaded the source code from the wireshar.org and tried to build it but I am facing the problem in compiling it.

Following is the error I am getting during configure (./configure)

```
checking for Qt5 core - version >= 4.6.0... no
checking for Qrcore - version >= 4.6.0.. no
configure: error: Qt is not avilable.
```

I installed the qt and it is visible in yum list qt, I think required version is >= 4.6. Following is installed version of qt in my machine.

```
qt.i386   1:3.3.6.26el5 installed.
```

I tried to install qt5 using the yum, but not able to find it. Please let me know how could I install qt5 on centos 5.3 and build wireshark.

I have asked same question on the [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812684/unable-to-build-wireshark-in-the-centos-5-3)

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it for 100% right now (don't have rhel based distro by the hand), but it should be something like this:

```
yum install qt4-devel
```

Comment: I successfully installed the qt4 using the yum, but still it is complaining same issue. I think it require qt 4.6.